# UK citizen looking to get residency in the Netherlands

Tags: united-kingdom, netherlands, residency, brexit

I am a UK citizen and I'm looking to relocate to the Netherlands.
I have a company in the UK that I don't want to close down.
Can I get residency in NL while carrying on holding a company and being a UK employee?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I get residency in NL while carrying on holding a company and being a UK employee?

Probably so.  But act quickly: you can still move to the Netherlands under EU free movement rules during the rest of this year (2020).  It is not yet clear what the situation will be next year, but it is likely to be much more difficult.

To establish yourself in the Netherlands under the free movement regime, you'll need to show that you qualify as a worker (including self-employed), a student, a self-sufficient person, or the family member of one of these.

Whether you can keep working as an employee of your UK company will depend on several factors, including tax law and labor law.  It might make more sense for you to change your relationship to the company if you're neither residing nor performing any work for the company in the UK. You should consult a lawyer who is familiar with these matters in the UK and the Netherlands.